# You'll find me when you reach not 21, but more - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

An American brand of shampoo, I'm quite the work of art.
I come with a boom and can sadden your heart.
You'll find me when you reach not 21, but more.
I'm measured and sometimes even lusted for.

I'll also be there when you're caught doing wrong
and I'll happen on the dance floor during a song.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My answer is

> Bust

An American brand of shampoo, I'm quite the work of art.

> A bust is a sculpture of a person that includes just their 'head and shoulders'.

I come with a boom and can sadden your heart.

> In economics, bust and boom are opposites. A bust is usually marked by a period of depression.

You'll find me when you reach not 21, but more.

> In Black Jack, if you go over 21, you go bust.

I'm measured and sometimes even lusted for.

> A woman's chest measured around her breasts is her bust.

I'll also be there when you're caught doing wrong

> A police raid or search is known as a bust.

and I'll happen on the dance floor during a song.

> 'Bust a move', which means to dance.

Comment: Line 2 is more in line with an economical bust but otherwise spot on. (Boom bust cycle, of which a bust can lead to a depression)

Comment: @hypern Yes, thank you, I was just thinking about that.

Comment: Yeah, 21 is definitely *good* in blackjack, not [the answer].

Comment: Sorry! I used the wrong word, I'll edit the riddle.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be a

> Drop ?

An American brand of shampoo

> not sure bout this one

I'm quite the work of art.

> A drop can be a work of art, like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Drop_(sculpture))

I come with a boom

> Rain with a storm

and can sadden your heart

> Teardrop

You'll find me when you reach 21 or more.

> Alcohol?

I'm measured

> A measure of volume

and sometimes even lusted for

> third world countries don't have water

I'll also be there when you're caught doing wrong

> If my parents cought me smoking, they would say "drop" it

and I'll happen on the dance floor during a song.

> Beat "drop" in the song